# Problems aligning radio buttons with text

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have the following markup:

```
    <ul>
    <label class="radio-label" for="${response[i].name}"><li><span>${freightName}:</span> ${response[i].price},-</li></label>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" id="${response[i].name}" name="drone" value="${response[i].name}-radio-value">
    </ul>
```

I get this as the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRZXZ.png)

I tried to set the label to position: absolute; but this just makes it more difficult to space vertically after, is there anyone who can give me a tip or two? Any help is greatly appreciated !

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, please explain what you expect from the solution.

Comment: sorry about that, i meant to say that i need to vertically align the radio buttons to the text :)

Comment: @Freshtone, Did you manage to line up the label and radio button in one line (vertically align)? If not, then I can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using HTML tags incorrectly. Please don't put any other tags in `<ul>` except `<li>`.

Refer:
[ul tag documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

You might try something like this, which would put a label on top of a list item with radio button:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>Label</label>
    <input class="radio-input" type="radio">
    <span>hi</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/akshaygpt/pen/VwmBYYj)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `<ul>` tag and the `<li>` tag incorrectly. Here is the correct structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        any tags
    </li>
    <li>
        any tags
    </li>
    <li>
        any tags
    </li>
</ul>
```

Do it like this, wrapping it in a `<li>...</li>` tag.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label class="radio-label" for="${response[i].name}"><span>${freightName}:</span> ${response[i].price},-</label>
        <input class="radio-input" type="radio" id="${response[i].name}" name="drone" value="${response[i].name}-radio-value" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply ! i managed to get it working in the ned, it was as you said with the wrong usage of Lists and ul and li and such :) cheers !

Comment: @Freshtone, I am very glad that you managed to solve this problem. If there are questions, let me know.